# Parser interpreter programming

Tags: algorithm, delphi, parsing, compiler-construction, formula

I want to program a package that calculates the resulting value of a certain input formula,

I created the parser due to the Shunting-Yard Algorithm (Dijikstra), 
I want to create libraries of the functions that the user will be allowed to use (for ex: `sin()` and `cos()` functions)
then I was wondering what my next step should be; so I have some questions:

1. What is more simpler to use, the Shunting Yard Algorithm, or the Recursive-Descent algorithm for parsing the formulas?
2. will i reach the work of the interpreter in some stage of my work, and how?

Thanks...

Please note that i am programming it using Delphi

Comment: you may want to give this a try http://www.pegtop.net/delphi/components/math/download.htm

Comment: `[1]` - what does it mean to be "simple"? `[2]` - you need to elaborate. We don't have your notes from class!

Comment: No, it is not a homework, im not anymore in uni.

Comment: I meant by Simple:
simpler to program using recursive methods, or in ohter words, more simple to deal with concerning the internal functions that im gonna use later.

Comment: "Dealing with your internal functions" isn't going to be the hardest part, and it'll be about the same no matter what parsing algorithm you're going to use. If you prefer a recursive implementation you'll probably prefer the Recursive Descent algorithm as it is, well, recursive!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is more simpler to use, the Shunting Yard Algorithm, or the Recursive-Descent algorithm for parsing the formulas?

The simplest would be the one you understand better. If there's a tie I'd go with recursive-descent, it can be used for both plain expressions and more complex scripts (ie: interpreter).

If this is not homework (hence you're not required to implement the code yourself), look into ready-made solutions (example: [dwscript](http://code.google.com/p/dwscript/), or [Pascal Script](http://www.remobjects.com/ps.aspx)). You can also use a "compiler compiler", a toolset designed for producing lexycal analyzers and parsers. I can't recommend any because, to be honest, I haven't found one to satisfy my needs. You can start your search with [TP Lex/Yacc](http://www.musikwissenschaft.uni-mainz.de/~ag/tply/).

> will i reach the work of the interpreter in some stage of my work, and how?

An interpreter would usually work on a script and perform multiple operations (execute statements). An expression evaluator only works with expressions, providing a result (or an expression tree that can be used to obtain the result).

An interpreter would definitively need an expression parser (or evaluator), but not the other way around.

Comment: may i ask an additional quest?
Can the interpreter while executing a script execute a predefined script?
as performing a function that is not built in it, but defined by the user?

Comment: I suppose this is a `how`, not a `if` question. The answer to the `if` is obviously *yes* (`Python` is an interpreted language, and Python can do anything that can be done). The "how" is a matter of your design, and definitively too large a subject for a comment. Feel free to ask a new question (the Ask Question button at the top-right) and ask for implementation ideas.

Comment: Or just look at the JVCL JvInterpreter which includes a simple pascal implementation of just such a thing.

Comment: dwscript and PascalScript (I like PascalScript better, but I've worked with both) are both open source, one can also look in there. To be perfectly honest for the OP, if you need to ask for implementation details, you're probably not prepared to undertake this *just yet*. Unless you do it for fun and entertainment (and I honestly *see* the entertainment value in designing something like this)

Comment: What should i do to be prepared? I am reading more about this Pascal Script, but is it compatible with Delphi 2010? As i saw it is only compatible till 2009... Actually it is for work, but i can see fun in this too. is it compatible also with win7,64-bits?

Comment: Just download the engine, install it and give it a try. There's a learning curve with any scripting engine, you'll need to learn how to make your (compiled) code available in the scripting engine. `dwscript` promises RTTI-based import, but it didn't quite work when I tried it.

Comment: If Pascal Script has Delphi 2009 packages, they probably work unchanged for all post-2009 32 bit versions of Delphi. They almost certainly don't work for the 64 bit version of Delphi XE2 because all 32 bit assembler code needs to be re-written for 64 bits (and scripting engines naturally contain quite a bit of assembler, to set up calls from the script to compiled code).

Answer (score 11):

Having implemented both (and still maintaining systems with both), here is my pro/con list:

- Shunting Yard:

  - code is short
  - easy when associated to simple rules/priority tables
  - annoying to debug when something goes wrong
- Recursive Descent:

  - code is longer
  - more complex when all you have are simple rules/priorities
  - easier to extend or add special-case syntaxes
  - relatively simpler to debug (follows a more "human" flow)

Or in other words, when you're dealing only with math formulas, Shunting Yard is probably the way to go, but if you feel you may need for more complexity later on, recursive descent might be more flexible/extensible/maintainable and pay back in the long run.

Compiler's compilers (Lex/Yacc, Flex/Bison etc.) would be an obvious third choice, but I don't know any maintained implementation for Delphi, and for simple maths formulas, they're overkill.